Azure blob storage authorization error with cypress
I am trying to access audio snippets within an application hosted on Azure blob storage during a cypress test and I keep getting
"403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."
The app works fine when I use it manually through browser, but fails during Cypress run.
this is my cypress config
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'https://tts-sa-dev.azurewebsites.net',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here 
    },
  },
});

I use a basic auth before every test suite
beforeEach(() => cy.authenticate('basic')); 

that looks like this

Cypress.Commands.add('authenticate', (authType: 'basic') => {
  if (authType === 'basic') {
    
    const username = 'XXXX'; 
    const password = 'XXXX'; 
    const authHeader = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);

    // Intercept all requests and add the Authorization header
    cy.intercept('**', (req) => {
      req.headers['Authorization'] = authHeader;
    });
  }
});


Im not sure if the auth header could be somehow interacting with the cors signature from azure and there seems to be nobody else on stackoverflow dealing with this, which i find strange.
I've simplified the test to bare bones, but it fails to retrieve any data after calling the endpoint.
I realize cypress is probably modifying the request header but I fail to log any difference when intercepting it.
Anybody has a similar problem?
I have compared request headers and there were some discrepancies:
There was an "origin" header missing, "accept" was an array of options and "fetch-mode" was non-cors, but adjusting them made no difference.

cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
      console.log('Request Headers at Intercept:', req.headers);
      req.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
      req.headers['Origin'] = 'https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net';
      req.headers['Sec-Fetch-Mode'] = 'cors';
      req.headers['Accept-Language'] = 'cs,en;q=0.9';
    });



I think you need header names to start lower case.
If you look at Passing a request to the next request handler, it uses lower-case authorization but you have upper-case Authorization.

cy.intercept('http://api.company.com/', { middleware: true }, (req) => {
  req.headers['authorization'] = `token ${token}`
})


If I try a sample test with req.headers['Origin'] it passes (but it shouldn't)
cy.intercept(/todos/, (req) => {

  const defaultHeaders = Cypress._.cloneDeep(req.headers)
  console.log('Request Headers at Intercept:', defaultHeaders)

  req.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  req.headers['Origin'] = 'https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net';
  req.headers['Sec-Fetch-Mode'] = 'cors';
  req.headers['Accept-Language'] = 'cs,en;q=0.9';
})
.as('request-headers')

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
})  

cy.wait('@request-headers').then(({request,response}) => {
  console.log(request.headers)
  expect(request.headers['Origin']).to.eq('https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net')
})

In the final console.log() there are upper-case and lower-case headers for "Origin/origin" keys, which indicates the header key is case sensitive.
Origin: "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net",
origin: "http://localhost:34272"


If I switch to lower-case req.headers['origin'] it now fails with a CORS error, which I think is correct behavior.
From that I would conclude the correct format for setting header keys is to use lower-case strings.
Not sure this is the complete answer, but should get you one step further.

Basic auth on cy.visit()
The cy.visit() - Add basic auth headers documentation shows how to use basic auth in the visit command.
cy.visit('https://wile:coyote@tts-sa-dev.azurewebsites.net/')

or

cy.visit('https://tts-sa-dev.azurewebsites.net/', {
  auth: {
    username: 'wile',
    password: 'coyote',
  },
})

This should make a single test test authenticated, push to beforeEach() to do it for each test.
Wrap in a cy.session to cache the login credentials.
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
  cy.session([username, password], () => {
    cy.visit('https://wile:coyote@tts-sa-dev.azurewebsites.net/')
  })
})

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.login('wile', 'coyote')
})


yes, you're right, header keys are case sensitive, unfortunately it doesn't help :/

Tryn the visit instead of intercept.

Ok so I've found a solution -
the problem seems to be in the basic auth
beforeEach(() => cy.authenticate('basic')); 

Azure has some kind of a problem with basic auth and doesn't do well with authorization header.
Instead I have used
beforeEach(() => cy.visit('https://username:password@app-name.azurewebsites.net'));

Works fine now

So you did what TesterDick suggested - cy.visit('https://wile:coyote@tts-sa-dev.azurewebsites.net/'). You should accept that answer then.

honestly i only noticed the second part of his answer now that you mentioned it:) but youre right, it is the correct approach and i salute him
